# Pure Javascript plugin development

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to develop a pure javascript plugin wich can be accessed like jquery typed plugins ( `$('.pluginWrapper').pluginInit();`

However i need to to use pure javascript and i was thinking maybe about 2 supported formats:

```
document.getElementById('pluginWrapper').pluginInit();
pluginInit(document.getElementById('pluginWrapper'));
```

I know that you have to do an IIFE to wrap it and call it via object methods but i do not know how i can bind that to an element.

I am mentioning that i am a begginer so please can someone please explain something about this. Cheers!

Comment: thank's for the edditing , i am kinda sloppy today, do you have any answers too, or any indications ?

Comment: Why not just look at [jQuery's source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery)?

Comment: Well, that's kinda hard to figure out isn't it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would be safer developing a plugin interface that simply exposes plugins as functions which take an element as an argument.

```
function MyPlugin(element) {
  // do stuff with element
  element.setAttribute('data-plugin-id', 'pluginName');
}
```

The other approach involves extending `Element.prototype`. Which could potentially be [a dangerous action](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/) in production software.

However, it is still possible.

```
Element.prototype.pluginInit = function() {
  // the element is accessible as `this`
  this.setAttribute('data-plugin-id', 'pluginName');
}
```

A function is easy for everyone to understand. Plugin writers don't have to understand any interfaces for creating and registering plugins, they just need to know that they should write functions that take elements as arguments.

There's a great talk from Rich Hickey (the creator of Clojure) called [Simplicity Matters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rI8tNMsozo0) in which he stresses that the worst thing you can do is add additional complexity when simple solutions will do.

In this case, you don't need anything more complex than a function which takes an element as an argument.

---

If it is completely essential that you have control of the function, you could write a simple interface for registering and initiating plugins.

```
function Plugin(element) {
  if(element === null) {
    throw new TypeError("Element must not be null!");
  }

  // get all the plugin names from the store
  var pluginNames = Object.keys(Plugin.store);

  // make sure `this` is set to the element for each plugin
  var availablePlugins = pluginNames.reduce(function(plugins, name) {
    plugins[name] = Plugin.store[name].bind(element);
    return plugins;
  }, {});

  // return an object containing all plugins
  return availablePlugins;
}

// we'll store the plugins in this object
Plugin.store = {};

// we can register new plugins with this method
Plugin.register = function(name, pluginFn) {
  Plugin.store[name] = pluginFn;
};
```

Which you could use like this.

```
Plugin.register('myPlugin', function() {
  this.setAttribute('data-plugin-id', 'myPlugin');
});

Plugin(document.getElementById('pluginWrapper')).myPlugin();
```

---

If you want the plugin function to take a selector, the same way as jQuery, then you can use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) inside your definition for `Plugin`.

```
function Plugin(selector) {
  var element = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

  if(element === null) {
    throw new TypeError("Element must not be null!");
  }

  // get all the plugin names from the store
  var pluginNames = Object.keys(Plugin.store);

  // make sure `this` is set to the element for each plugin
  var availablePlugins = pluginNames.reduce(function(plugins, name) {
    plugins[name] = Plugin.store[name].bind(element);
    return plugins;
  }, {});

  // return an object containing all plugins
  return availablePlugins;
}
```

Then you would use it like this instead.

```
Plugin.register('myPlugin', function() {
  this.setAttribute('data-plugin-id', 'myPlugin');
});

Plugin('#pluginWrapper').myPlugin();
```

Comment: one question though, do you know how can i make a custom wrapper.. let's say like $.ajax which i know it wraps the  XMLHttpRequest.. so maybe that way i can cerate a wrapper around my plugin

Comment: It depends what you mean by a wrapper. $.ajax is primarily a new API around some XHR and some polyfills to make sure the user can do AJAX in a cross platform way. Why do you need to create a wrapper around plugins?

Comment: i have studied a lot about this included the link you provided about the danger of expanding dom elements. For example if i wanna do var x = document.getElementByID('test').plugin({ size : 100, effect : 'slide')}.. i suppose i need to have a jquery like wrapper ($)

Comment: The second approach I identified is exactly this. The wrapper is the Plugin function. Simply call it with the name of the plugin you want to register and the function which makes it work. If you wanted you could alias `var $ = Plugin`. Then you could do `$(document.getElementById('test')).plugin()`.

Comment: the (jqeury) or  $ wrapper elements are really hard to reproduce. i have tried 3 different approches with no success, i am unable to make a javascript module that behaves the same as $ on selection of elements.. i only achived something like $.select();

Comment: Updated the answer to make sure the code works and also added an example of the way you can make the Plugin function works more like the jQuery function.